# sed: Delete match and newline (with CRLF)

Tags: awk, text, sed, find

I want to query for `console.log` in all files in a directory, then delete lines that match with the newline after those lines. AWK, Perl, Powershell and Windows solutions are welcome too (besides sed).

However, because I'm on Windows, my code ends with CRLF so plain sed `/d` doesn't work. It just replace the line by a blank one.

Before:

```js
hello.world();
console.log("Debug info");
foo.bar();
```

After:

```js
hello.world();
foo.bar();
```

The current command I used, `find pages -type f -exec sed -i -e '/console.log/d' {} \;` only replaces a line with a blank line like:

```js
hello.world();

foo.bar();
```

Here are some screenshots to verify what I'm saying.

[image: Running Command]

[image: Github Desktop diff before and after]

Comment: Please [don’t post images of code, error messages, or other textual data.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors)

Comment: I think i know why: it's because of CR LF. If you know how to solve this, I'd be more than pleased. If not please reopen the question.

Comment: yeah so how do i solve my problem. I don't want to convert a multi-team app to LF immediately.

Comment: Yeah I just want to remove `console.log`s. a cmd/powershell alternative would be the best actually.

Comment: Kudos for managing to diagnose the source of the problem. DOS line endings leave many of us stumped.

Comment: alright thanks. thank you too for helping me diagnose the solution. I was getting pretty mad which I'm sorry about. I wish you a happy new year

Comment: Programmatically removing all logging statements from your code seems like a dubious practice anyway. Wouldn't it be better to make the logging controllable with an option?

Answer (score 1):

In theory the `d` command in `sed` should remove the entire line, but lines with DOS line endings are a pesky corner case; clearly, not all `sed` versions operate correctly in their presence.

If you are willing to use Perl instead, this should be straightforward:

```
perl -ni -e 'print unless /console\.log/' pages/**
```

Demo: https://ideone.com/NNYocH

(The wildcard `pages/**` is not portable, but convenient in place of `find` if you have a shell which supports this.)

If you have GNU Awk, you can similarly use that with the `-i inplace` option to overwrite the input files.

```
awk -i inplace 'BEGIN{RS=ORS="\r\n"} !/console\.log/' pages/**
```

There may be a similar problem with DOS CR line endings with some Awk versions, but I believe GNU Awk should cope.

Finally, here is a variant which uses a temporary file, and should work with any Awk.

```
find pages -type f -exec sh -c '
    for file; do
        awk "BEGIN{RS=ORS=\"\\r\\n\"} !/console\.log/" "$file" >"$file.$$"
        mv "$file.$$" "$file"
    done' _ {} +
```

Modern versions of `find` should allow you to use `+` instead of `\;` after `-exec`, which should be significantly more performant than spawning a new subprocess for each found file.

Notice how a literal dot in a regular expression should properly be backslash-escaped or put in a character class (an unquoted dot is a regex special character which matches any character except newline).

Comment: The perl command doesn't work (it also replaces the newlines with blank lines, not delete them). awk does the same thing as well but it's also verrrrrrrrrry slow.

Comment: The Perl one works for me, but I fortunately don't have a Windows system where I can check it. If you are not using a Unix-compatible shell, you may have to use different quoting.

Comment: I'm using bash through Windows Terminal on WSL

Comment: I updated with another Awk variation but I have no idea if it will be any faster than the GNU Awk `-i inplace` one. In my experience Awk is usually quite fast. My suspicions would lie with the usual Windows braindeath (do you have these files open in an editor at the same time, or something?)

Comment: the new awk variation is somehow faster (7.069s compared to 8.449s) but it doesn't correctly replace CRLF